# Error when compiling SDL2 on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: c, sdl-2

I get an error when trying to compile SDL2 in my Raspberry Pi, I copy-pasted the log below.

```
/bin/bash build-scripts/updaterev.sh
  CC     build/SDL_sndioaudio.lo
/home/luca/SDL2/src/audio/sndio/SDL_sndioaudio.c: In function 'SNDIO_CaptureFromDevice':
/home/luca/SDL2/src/audio/sndio/SDL_sndioaudio.c:187:46: error: 'INFTIM' undeclared (first use in this function)
             || poll(this->hidden->pfd, nfds, INFTIM) < 0) {
                                              ^
/home/luca/SDL2/src/audio/sndio/SDL_sndioaudio.c:187:46: 
note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
```

How can I fix the issue? I'm not fluent in C, tried looking in the manual and it says that INFTIM can also be absent from glibc and that might be the reason it is not declared.

Answer (score 1):

```
man poll
```

says:

```
Some implementations define the nonstandard constant INFTIM with the value -1
```

So I added

```
#define INFTIM -1
```

On top of the source file. Not sure it's the best approach but it works.